# hover function have three function how to merge them?

Tags: jquery

if the hover function have three effect(three function). how to merge the function?

```
$('li.cat-item:has(ul.children)').addClass('expand');
$('.productgroup-list .expand').hover(function(){
    $('li.cat-item:has(ul.children)').addClass('open');
}, function() {
    $('li.cat-item:has(ul.children)').removeClass( "open" );
});
$('.productgroup-list .expand').hover(function(){
    $('ul li.child').show();
});
```

why the last hover effect can't work.

**(**`$('.productgroup-list .expand').hover(function(){
            $('ul li.child').show();`**)**

how to correct it? thank you.

Answer (score 0):

No need to separate it out. Keep the code in hover itself:

```
$('.productgroup-list .expand').hover(function() {
    // add relevant code here only
    $('ul li.child').show();
    $('li.cat-item:has(ul.children)').addClass('open');
}, function() {
    $('li.cat-item:has(ul.children)').removeClass('open');
});
```